# Issues connecting to Microsoft Exchange online

Tags: azure, powershell, office365

I am working on a project to run a security & compliance search. This will be used by multiple users and the project is to centralise this action. For reasons, I want to do this outside of the security & compliance centre. This is where the idea of creating a PowerShell script to run based on the actions of the user.

For this, I are looking into using the Azure Automation runbooks as a method of running a script to search. The end goal is to run `New-ComplianceSearch` in order to search mailboxes for emails that fit given criteria.

However, I am having some issues with the remote connection, outlined below:

Last week, the remote connection sometimes works (optimistically about 40%-50% of the time) but most times it fails with an Access Denied error and yet nothing is different with the PowerShell script and the credentials are definitely correct. 
This week I only get the Access Denied error and nothing has happened to the account or script.

I am able to connect with no issues using the Microsoft Exchange Online PowerShell Module but this is only used for testing out the process and cannot be used to achieve the project goal.

Connection code, there is no previous code except for getting the credentials:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

Access Denied Error Message:

```
New-PSSession : [ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com] Connecting to remote server ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com 
failed with the following error message: Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting 
Help topic.
At line:31 char:16
+ ...  $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Conn ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], 
PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

I have also been trying to connect to outlook.office365.com using the same method and am also getting the same error.

Has anyone ever come across a similar issue where the credentials and access are correct for the connection but they are still getting `Access is Denied`?

Could there be some configuration on the office 365 side of things or networking (ports opened, etc) that could be blocking the access?

Alternatively, does anyone know of another way to efficiently search mailboxes for emails that fit a given criterion?